# ruby variable name conflict with method name

Tags: ruby

ruby code

```
def something
  p 'hellp something'
  'hello'
end

p something + 'xx'
p '-----------'
something = something + 'xx'
```

The last code run error:

> test01.rb:11:in `<main>': undefined method`+' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

This is my understanding of the last code:

1. ruby explain the code from left to right.
2. Ruby parser see 'something' first, then it will see '=' on the right. So, it think the 'something' as a variable and its value is nil.
3. Ruby parser will see the second 'something', but do not know this is a variable or a method. So, it looks up the same name variable or method. Then it find the nil value 'something'. " nil + 'xx' " this code run with error.

I do not know whether my understanding is correct.

Comment: please, use English on this resource.

Comment: OK, I have use English on this resource, thank you.

Comment: Yes, this is more or less what happens.

Answer (score 1):

In ruby everything is a class.

The line that is messing up your code is `something = something + 'xx'` at this moment the compiler is going to mix up everything in the following sequence.

1. the first `something` is given the `nil` value (from the NilClass)
2. the second `something` at the right of the equal sign is no longer associated with the method `something` you previously defined but to the nil object that was defined at step #1.
3. then, and this is when the error is triggered, you try to perform an operation on a nil object that is not allowed in ruby.